# Sending core data files from documents directory

Tags: ios, core-data, dropbox

I have a core data app, I am sending the sqlite files to Dropbox.

```
//Upload files

NSString *filePath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myApp.sqlite"];
NSString *filePath1 = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myApp.sqlite-shm"];
NSString *filePath2 = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myApp.sqlite-wal"];


[restClient uploadFile:@"myApp.sqlite" toPath:@"/Data" withParentRev:nil fromPath:filePath];
[restClient uploadFile:@"myApp.sqlite-shm" toPath:@"/Data" withParentRev:nil fromPath:filePath1];
[restClient uploadFile:@"myApp.sqlite-wal" toPath:@"/Data" withParentRev:nil fromPath:filePath2];
```

Problem is with this method is the -WAL file lags behind and sometimes doesn't arrive.  Ive tried to making a zip folder with ZipArchive but when it arrives it can never be opened. The sqlite, wal and shm are the only files in the documents directory so ive tried creating a folder to upload in one go but couldn't get this to upload correctly to Dropbox.  I could just stop journal mode and have the single sqlite file, any pitfalls of doing this with an app that currently using journal mode?  On testing, stopping journal mode on the update didn't cause any problems with lost data but not sure if something wouldnt come out the woodwork later on a s this app is live on the appstore with journal mode on.

Comment: There is one thing you can do like read all data from Coredata and create a sqlite file and uplaod it dropbox.

Comment: Another approach that you could try is to make a copy of the files to be uploaded and clean it up afterwards.